# RBAC Access Control in tree structure

Tags: php, mysql, rbac

I am implimenting role based access control in a tree structure (organization) that normally would be stored in LDAP but this time is in MySQL. Part of my requirement is to give people acccess to part of the tree. In LDAP I would use a ACI to filter part of the tree. I am just not sure on the best way to do this in PHP/MySQL.

What is the best way in a LAMP application to create a way for the permission to be applied to collections of objects as well as to individual entities within the hierarchy?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: the schema that you have so far would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

RBAC and ACL are pretty ubiquitous

http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/role-based-access-control.html

... or you can just use one of a dozen FOSS frameworks that already have that built in.  Though without more context I can't tell if that is possible for you or not.

Comment: note: this site is a little outdated, but RBAC hasn't exactly changed much in the last 6 years :-)